# Does the kubelet validate PodSecurityPolicy?

Tags: kubernetes

I described a pod in Kubernetes and saw the following error from the kubelet:

```
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  12m (x835 over 36m)    kubelet, ip-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.internal  (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "5608c825cd175d595a89be91a27ba971e4160066a8d4690ef2ab29358dec8675" network for pod "coredns-747c45d54-627wn": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-747c45d54-627wn_kube-system" network: connection is unauthorized: pods "coredns-747c45d54-627wn" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_BIND_SERVICE": capability may not be added spec.containers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_BIND_SERVICE": capability may not be added]
```

My question is around the `unable to validate against any pod security policy` part - my understanding of pod security policy is that the validation checks happen only at apiserver admission time (and are performed by the [pod security policy admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#enabling-pod-security-policies)) and so when the kubelet sees that it needs to run a pod it assumes it has already been validated, but this seems to not be the case and the kubelet is also performing validation.

Am I correct in saying this and is this behaviour documented anywhere? Or have I misinterpreted the error message?

Kubernetes version: 14.1

Comment: Hi, yea that's true, kubelet can also perform few validations. Here is also one of the usecase https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/auth/pod-security-policy.md#interaction-with-the-kubelet

Comment: awesome, thanks for the link - trying to find in the code the specific interaction above but have failed to do so far, but that shows that behaviour is as the event suggests